# web developer express - two questions

Tags: c#, visual-studio

First question is:
- I have a sql well-formatted string and I want to paste it in a c# file in web dev. express. I do not remember how I can let the IDE to automatically add "" + for the string I paste.

Do you know how?

Second one:
- when I navigate from a class to another in the tabs I want that class to automatically be selected on the right side in Solution Explorer. Do you know how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a multiline string literal instead.

```
    string multiLine = @"line1
line2
line3";
```

Note that line2 and 3 has no indentation.

For the navigation part:

Tools -> Options: Projects and Solutions –> General –> Track Active Item in Solution Explorer
(from [101 Visual Studio tips](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/nicfill/sara-fords-101-visual-studio-tips-in-55-minutes-challenge)).

Comment: Awesome! One more (last one hopefully:): Do you know how I can quickly go to a class if I know it's name? To type it somewhere and press enter...like in IntelliJIdea ctrl_Shift_n ?

Comment: @Cristian Boariu, in Visual Studio 2010 you press Ctrl+, (Ctrl+comma). But I'm not sure that is available in the Express-editions.

Comment: In Visual C# 2010 Express right-click, Go To Definition, bound to F12 hot-key by default.